# How to link the Valgrind 3.11.0 in my MacBook Pro (El Capitan)?

Tags: c, bash, homebrew, valgrind

First of all, my Mac OS version is 10.11.3 (El Capitan).

So, I am learning c through http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/. It's a tutorial by Zed A. Shaw. On that tutorial, he asked the reader to instal the Valgrind. The steps are as below:

```
# 1) Download it (use wget if you don't have curl)
curl -O http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2

# use md5sum to make sure it matches the one on the site
md5sum valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2

# 2) Unpack it.
tar -xjvf valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2

# cd into the newly created directory
cd valgrind-3.6.1

# 3) configure it
./configure

# 4) make it
make

# 5) install it (need root)
sudo make install
```

So, I did as above and got stuck at step 4. If I am not mistaken, the command line said no target to be make (something like that). I'm realised then that it is not the latest version of Valgrind, so by using exactly the above steps, I've managed to install the latest one. I managed to go until step 5 although sometimes there are some negative messages from the command line during installation.

The problem is, whenever I enter valgrind, the command prints `-bash: valgrind: command not found`. Then through `brew doctor`, this message is printed:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
valgrind
```

When I type `brew link valgrind`, this message is printed out:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/valgrind/callgrind.h
/usr/local/include/valgrind is not writable.
```

I even tried `brew install --HEAD valgrind` and this message is printed out:

```
Warning: valgrind-3.11.0 already installed, it's just not linked
```

What is happening? How can I fix this? Is this thing happened because of my mistake in trying to install an outdated Valgrind before by using the `make` command (although the `make` command cannot be executed at that time if I remember correctly)?

Comment: can you give us the output of `brew link -v valgrind`?

Comment: @cel The output is    `Error: Could not symlink include/valgrind/callgrind.h
/usr/local/include/valgrind is not writable.`

Comment: If you're installing through Homebrew I would check the permissions on /usr/local and it's subfolders, Homebrew does not seem to be able to write there. If you're trying to do the installation manually, i.e. by following the steps in your tutorial, you're going to have to pass a prefix flag to configure (/usr/local is the best dir to install your *nix apps to), as the usual system directories are not writeable, not even for root, which is why the 'make install' command is going to fail unless you configure it to install somewhere else.

Comment: @eaxix So, what should I do to repair this? I am not really an expert on handling command line etc.. For most part, I always just do it through tutorials or instructions given.

Comment: @Hilman You could try recursively changing the owner of /usr/local to yourusername:admin(group) by running 'sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local' and then rerunning the brew link command.

Comment: @eaxix Thanks! It works! After entered above line, I just `brew link valgrind` it and followed the prompted instructions. A little question though, when I run it, it does say `Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX`. But, as I wrote above, at first try, I accidentally tried to install the old version but I kinda get stuck during the 4th step (the `make` step).  If I am right, the message of "no file to be make" was shown. Before the 4th step, I already `./configure` the old version Valgrind. Does it in any ways will cause me troubles or interferes with my now installed Valgrind? Just to be sure.